# Sentido de "disingenuous" pode ser captado com rigor em Português?

Tags: tradução-inglês

Acho esta palavra do Inglês curiosa: "Disingenuous".

Qual é a tradução mais correcta?

No dicionário [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disingenuous):

> **Definition of *disingenuous***
>
> : lacking in candor also : giving a false appearance of simple frankness : calculating

No dicionário [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/pt/dicionario/ingles/disingenuous):

> **Disingenuous**:
>
> (of a person or their behaviour) slightly dishonest, or not speaking the complete truth:
> It was disingenuous of her to claim she had no financial interest in the case.

Comment: _dissimulado_ talvez seja a mais proxima

Comment: Tens razão @Artefacto, se tomarmos a palavra sem contexto, sozinha por si mesma, acho que dissimulado é o mais próximo. Mas a resposta do Centauros foi de facto muito boa, o sentido concreto da palavra depende do contexto com que é usada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disingenuous** é um adjetivo da língua inglesa definido como:

> Someone who is disingenuous is slightly dishonest and insincere in what they say.
>   [formal] e.g. It would be disingenuous to claim that this is great art.
>   Synonyms: dishonest, cunning, sly, designing.   [**from Collins**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/disingenuous)
>
> **Usage Note** from [The Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/disingenuous): Disingenuous means "not ingenuous," that is, not innocent, naive, or guileless. **As such it can refer to someone who is insincere or calculating,** as in It is both insensitive and disingenuous for the White House to describe its aid package and the proposal to eliminate the federal payment as "tough love," or to someone who is pretending to be unsophisticated, as in "I don't have a clue about late Beethoven!" he said. The remark seemed disingenuous, coming from one of the world's foremost concert pianists. Both of these examples were accepted by 90 percent of the Usage Panel in our 2016 survey.

Diante das definições acima, **dependendo do contexto**, "disingenuous" poderá ser traduzido pelos adjetivos "falso", "dissimulado", "fingido", sonso ou até mesmo "hipócrita".

Comment: Vale também acrescentar as sugestões do [WordReference](https://www.wordreference.com/enpt/disingenuous): "velhaco, insincero, não confiável".

Comment: Pois, o problema desta palavra é o sentido depender do contexto. De maneira que não é possivel uma tradução directa sem circunstanciar. Em Português só um conjunto limitado de palavras são usadas para descrever falsidade, e todas elas se podem aplicar à tradução.

Comment: Não me parece que "simulado" possa ser usado para se referir a uma pessoa. Imagino que queria antes dizer "dissumulado"

Comment: @Rye   A typo.  I've fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Provavelmente, esta seria a tradução mais exata:

> **dis·si·mu·la·do** (particípio de dissimular)
>
> *adjectivo*
>
> 1. Que se dissimulou ou escondeu.
> 2. Que tem o hábito da dissimulação. ≠ AUTÊNTICO, VERDADEIRO
> 3. Disfarçado, encoberto.
> 4. Disposto de modo a não ser notado ou ser pouco notado.
>
> *adjectivo e substantivo masculino*
>
> 5. Que ou o que mostra algo que não corresponde àquilo que pensa ou sente. = FALSO, FINGIDO, HIPÓCRITA
>
> *"dissimulado", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2020, https://dicionario.priberam.org/dissimulado [consultado em 21-02-2020].*

ainda que, tal como foi referido no outro comentário, se possa usar falso, fingido ou hipócrita.

Não confundir com "simulado" (que, tanto quanto sei, não deve/costuma ser usado para se referir a uma pessoa):

> **si·mu·la·do**
>
> adjectivo
>
> 1. Fingido; disfarçado.
> 2. Aparente.
> 3. Suposto.
>
> *"simulado", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha],
>   2008-2020, https://dicionario.priberam.org/simulado [consultado em
>   21-02-2020].*

Answer (score 0):

O sítio Infopédia sugere as seguintes alternativas:

> **disingenuous**
>
> 1. pouco sincero, dissimulado
> 2. pouco franco
> 3. oculto
>
> *disingenuous in Dicionário infopédia de Inglês - Português [em linha]. Porto: Porto Editora, 2003-2020. [consult. 2020-03-08 19:10:30]. Disponível na Internet: https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/ingles-portugues/disingenuous*